# File Upload to S3 - 0 bytes

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mp3

I'm using the text-to-mp3 module to create an text-to-speech MP3 file. Right now, the file is being saved to my file system successfully. I'm trying to upload it to S3 as well. It shows up in S3, but the file is empty (0 bytes).

```
txtomp3.getMp3(myverse, function(err, binaryStream){

  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  var file = fs.createWriteStream("FileName.mp3"); // write it down the file
  file.write(binaryStream);
  file.end();

  var myfile = fs.createReadStream("FileName.mp3");

AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: '...', secretAccessKey: '...' });

  var s3 = new AWS.S3();
  s3.putObject({
    Bucket: 'myverses',
    Key: 'del2.mp3',
    Body: myfile,
    ACL: 'public-read'
  },function (resp) {
    console.log(arguments);
    console.log('Successfully uploaded package.');
  });
  });
  });
```

Comment: I think you should try `s3.upload` rather than `s3.putobject` because `myfile` is a stream. My guess is putobject will need content-length before hand

Answer (score 0):

[Uploading a File to an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html#s3-example-creating-buckets-upload-file) in the AWS Documentation has clear example on how to upload a file:

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

// Create S3 service object
s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

// call S3 to retrieve upload file to specified bucket
var uploadParams = {Bucket: process.argv[2], Key: '', Body: ''};
var file = process.argv[3];

var fs = require('fs');
var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
fileStream.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('File Error', err);
});
uploadParams.Body = fileStream;

var path = require('path');
uploadParams.Key = path.basename(file);

// call S3 to retrieve upload file to specified bucket
s3.upload (uploadParams, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } if (data) {
    console.log("Upload Success", data.Location);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution using upload method for store object in bucket as 0 byte in laravel`

**aws.php**

```
  return [
      'credentials' => [
      'key'    => 'XXXXX',
      'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXX',
  ],
  'region' => 'us-east-2',
  'version' => 'latest',
  ];


   $s3 = \App::make('aws')->createClient('s3');
   $adapter = new AwsS3Adapter($s3, 'bucket_name');
   $s4 = $adapter->getClient()->upload(
       'bucket_name',
       $fileName,
       fopen($imageFile->getPathName(), 'rb'),
       'authenticated-read',
       ['params' =>
          [
             'ContentType' => $imageFile->getClientMimeType()
          ]
       ]
   );
```

Any one help me using putObject

```
  $s3 = s3->putObject(array(
  'Bucket'     => 'bucket-name',
  'Key'        => $fileName,
  'sourceFile' => fopen($imageFile, 'rb'),
  'contentLength' => $imageFile->getClientSize(),
  'ACL'   => 'authenticated-read'
  ));
```